# Android Viewpager Tabs updating tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-viewpager

I have an Activity which scrapes a webpage in a CustomLoader.
When loader finished I want to update the contents of 3 tabs with the data retrieved.

I'm using the sample code provided by android dev samples to implement the Viewpager/Tabs/Fragments on the activity.

When the fragment is created for the tab the onCreateView is correctly called, all the widgets on the view are correctly located and mapped to the variables.

However, when I attempt to find the fragment from the Activity and call a method on the fragment to update its contents the variables are null.  Furthermore, calling getView also returns null - The instance of the fragment I'm retrieving from the TabsAdapter is not the correct instantiated instance ?

I've cut the code down to a single tab fragment, code in question is the call from onLoaderFinished to update the fragment.

All 3 tab fragments will be populated with data from a single loader, hence the loader being on the activity, not on the fragments.  I just need a way to tell the fragments to paint their new data.

```
public class InfoBloodStocksActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<BloodStocksLoaderResponse> {

    TabHost mTabHost;
    ViewPager  mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.info_bloodstocks_tabpager);


        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.infoBloodStocksTabPager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Daily stock").setIndicator("Daily stocks"),
                InfoBloodStocksPageFragment.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }

        loadStockDetailsFromWebsite();

    }



    private void loadStockDetailsFromWebsite() {
        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<BloodStocksLoaderResponse> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
        return new BloodStocksCustomLoader(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<BloodStocksLoaderResponse> loader, BloodStocksLoaderResponse response) {
        if (response.isNewStocksLoaded()) {

            InfoBloodStocksPageFragment fragment = (InfoBloodStocksPageFragment) mTabsAdapter.getItem(0);

            fragment.setNewImage(response.getDailyStocksImageURL());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<BloodStocksLoaderResponse> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }







    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    /**
     * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
     * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
     * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
     * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
     * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
     * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
     * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
     * tab changes.
     */
    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());

            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.

            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm calling setNewImage from the activity.

```
public class InfoBloodStocksPageFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private TextView mDescriptionText;

    private String mImageURL;

    private ImageLoader mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_bloodstocks_page, container, false);

        mImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bloodStocksPageImage);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.bloodStocksPageProgress);
        mTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bloodStockPageTitle);
        mDescriptionText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bloodStocksPageText);

        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDescriptionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return view;
    }


    public void setNewImage(String imageURL) {

        // why is mImageView null here ?
        // why does getView() return null here ?

        View view = getView();
        mImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bloodStocksPageImage);

        DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.loading_stock_figures)
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT)
            .build();

        mImageLoader.displayImage(imageURL, mImageView, displayImageOptions, new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted() {
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }

                mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete() {
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
                mImageView.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled() {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just started using http://square.github.com/otto/ for doing this.  The documentation on the site should be enough to get you started with it.